# Accessing JSON Key in Swift in a neater way

Tags: ios, swift

I wrote a small app in Swift for iOS that calls the health check service of an API, and displays its results on the screen. The results that are returned are in an NSArray which I convert to JSON via the SwiftyJSON package. This is the structure of the JSON:

```
{
  "clientClockOK" : true,
  "securityTokenOK" : true,
  "memcacheOK" : true,
  "databaseOK" : true
}
```

When I print out the health check to the screen e.g. clientClockOK, rather than hard coding the title of the health check attribute in the UILabel, I do the following to get the key:

```
private func getHealthCheckCriteria(apiDataJson: JSON) -> NSMutableArray
{
    let healthCheckCriteria: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    for (apiCheck, _) in apiDataJson
    {
        healthCheckCriteria.addObject(apiCheck as String)
    }

    return healthCheckCriteria
}
```

Is there a neater way to get the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is without knowing exactly what the type of `apiDataJson` is:

```
let healthCheckCriteria : [String] = apiDataJson.map { $0.0 as String }
```

Comment: Hey Gary, apiDataJson is of the JSON type. It's a type provided by the SwiftyJSON cocoapods package

Comment: I just had a look at the SwiftyJSON, and as `JSON` implements the `SequenceType` protocol, it has a `map` method and so the code I wrote should work.